# WordPress images and CSS not loading - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm getting a series of errors in my inspector console on my WordPress blog. I'm very confused by what could have set this off. When I check CPanel, all the images are there, in the correct locations. The problem arose when migrating my database to a new host. Obviously I messed something up, but I'm not sure. What do you think could go be going wrong?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
logo-black-orange-green-croatia.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #security: (More info: https://goo(dot)gl/9p2vKq) <input type=​"hidden" id=​"security" name=​"security" value=​"0d35b82291">​ <input type=​"hidden" id=​"security" name=​"security" value=​"0d35b82291">​
tired-480x334.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
heuristic-interface-480x320.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
opt-out-man-480x319.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bad-did-selo-480x320.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cognitive-dissonance-480x312.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
sail-boats-480x320.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
logo-black-orange-green-croatia.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
church-graveyard-480x360.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
tao-other-480x320.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
olives-480x252.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
dynamic.css
```

Here's a link to one of the failed images: http://selonomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/heuristic-interface-480x320.jpg

This links leads to a 404 but when I follow the path in CPanel, the image is certainly there and I can view and download it.

Comment: Is your site url updated to the new domain url?

Comment: looks like htaccess problem

Comment: I'm getting 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable. Did you switch IPs when migrating, and still have a cached DNS response to work with? See if your browser uses the same IP that dnswatch.info or similar tools report for your host.

Comment: The DNS could be messed up but I don't really have much experience here.

Comment: Look at your browser's development tools (F12), go to the network tab, reload your page. Click on one request and look for the IP address. 160.153.48.135 is the IP your DNS servers report. Is that also the correct IP of your new host?

Comment: @janh Yes, it is the same IP address of the new host.

Comment: Very strange. Have you checked permissions on the uploads folder and its subdirectories? Images from the theme directory get loaded, so it doesn't seem to be a general image problem.

Comment: @janh Yeah I went through each folder and changed the image permissions to 775, then 777. No changes.

Comment: i think you need to give permission 755 at list and check your .htaccess file

Comment: @HusainAhmed What would the htaccess file show that I'd be interested in?